# Using IPEGA bluetooth gamepad with Steam @ Linux

Tags: games, bluetooth, steam, gamepad

I have successfully paired gamepad IPEGA PG-9025 (bluetooth) with my notebook (Ubuntu 14.10).

IPEGA PG-9025 can handle 4 different device modes when pairing, but only one makes sense for Steam gaming - Joystick Mode, so I pressed X and Home keys together and pairing was successful in a minute.

Steam does not see my gamepad `/dev/input/js0` and I absolutely don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is working solution (you must create remapped virtual xbox gamepad using `xboxdrv` software, which works great in Steam Big Screen and Steam Games):

1. install xboxdrv `sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`
2. connect your ipega bluetooth gamepad and pair it with computer (hold X button and HOME button together, device is ready to pair when red LED blinking fast and successfully connected when red LED lights continuously)
3. find XX number (`/dev/input/eventXX`) of connected gamepad using command `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`
4. at the end, create virtual xbox compatible gamepad using command:

   ```
   sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/eventXX --evdev-absmap ABS_X=x1,ABS_Y=y1,ABS_Z=x2,ABS_RZ=y2,ABS_HAT0X=dpad_x,ABS_HAT0Y=dpad_y --axismap -Y1=Y1,-Y2=Y2 --evdev-keymap BTN_A=a,BTN_B=b,BTN_X=x,BTN_Y=y,BTN_TL=lb,BTN_TR=rb,BTN_TL2=lt,BTN_TR2=rt,BTN_THUMBL=tl,BTN_THUMBR=tr,BTN_SELECT=back,BTN_START=start --silent &
   ```

Don't forget to replace eventXX with value, discovered in step 3.

NOTE: remapping scheme, used in step 4. http://goo.gl/XFhYvI is usable probably only for ipega controllers, if you have another gamepad manufacturer, just follow these instructions https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/558748653738497361/.