# IPEGA bluetooth gamepad stops sending events after a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

I have an IPEGA PG-9025 bluetooth controller and I'm able to connect it to my Ubuntu 15.04 without problems.

It's added as a joystick (js) with all correct data and receiving input, but it stops sending events in a few seconds after connected. It's still listed, but it won't change input states as I press buttons.

I also remember using this controller model successfully using this same notebook, but it was on an earlier Ubuntu version. (13.XX?)

Can someone help me figure why is this happening?

**Kernel**

4.0.0-040000-generic

**Xorg log**

```
[  4011.670] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ipega media gamepad controller (/dev/input/mouse2)
[  4011.670] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  4011.670] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  4011.673] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ipega media gamepad controller (/dev/input/js0)
[  4011.673] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  4011.673] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  4011.721] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ipega media gamepad controller (/dev/input/event15)
[  4011.721] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  4011.721] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  4011.721] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ipega media gamepad controller'
[  4011.721] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: always reports core events
[  4011.721] (**) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Device: "/dev/input/event15"
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Vendor 0x1949 Product 0x402
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found 3 mouse buttons
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found scroll wheel(s)
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found relative axes
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found x and y relative axes
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found absolute axes
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found x and y absolute axes
[  4011.721] (--) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Found keys
[  4011.721] (II) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Configuring as mouse
[  4011.721] (II) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Configuring as keyboard
[  4011.721] (II) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Adding scrollwheel support
[  4011.721] (**) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  4011.721] (**) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[  4011.721] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:1949:0402.0008/input/input22/event15"
[  4011.721] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ipega media gamepad controller" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[  4011.721] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  4011.721] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  4011.721] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "br"
[  4011.721] (II) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: initialized for relative axes.
[  4011.721] (WW) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: ignoring absolute axes.
[  4011.722] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  4011.722] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  4011.722] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  4011.722] (**) ipega media gamepad controller: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  4026.788] (II) config/udev: removing device ipega media gamepad controller
[  4026.816] (II) evdev: ipega media gamepad controller: Close
[  4026.816] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All above I did only using the program Blueman to connect the controller. After I used BlueDevil from Kde, it suddenly works!

It's connected as a Joystick(js), so I have to use xboxdrv for it to work on most games and emulators, as seen here: [Using IPEGA bluetooth gamepad with Steam @ Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608386/using-ipega-bluetooth-gamepad-with-steam-linux)